# Embedding a UIView into a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview

How do you embed a `UIView` into a `UITableViewCell`? I want to use this animations library for my app, but it requires that whatever is being animated gets wrapped in a `UIView`, and I have no idea how to embed a `UIView` into a `UITableViewCell`. I've tried to click on the prototype cell and go to Editor > Embed, but the View option is grayed out. I've tried adding a UIView on storyboard and then placing a cell over it, but that didn't work too, and kept giving me an `NSInternalInconsistencyexception`.

For reference, the animation library I'm trying to use is the [Canvas animation library](https://medium.com/learning-xcode-as-a-designer/animate-in-xcode-without-code-20c82a904164). I want to achieve a pop effect on a cell when long pressed

Comment: You can't embed a table cell in a view. But a `UITableViewCell` has a `contentView` on which you should add your views. Have you looked at the code in the demo app of Canvas? It seems that the sample animations are done on table cells.

Comment: Ah, interesting. So, are you suggesting that I convert the `UIView` returned by `contentView` into a `CSAnimationView`, so that I can call the animations? I guess I'm slightly confused by what you mean by "add your views". I tried to look at the source code but its all in Obj-C, and I program entirely in Swift.

Comment: No, simply add your `CSAnimationView` as a subview to `contentView`. Something like this : `cell.contentView.addSubview(yourView);`

Answer (score 1):

UITableViewCell has a property `contentView` . This contentView property of UITableViewCell is of type UIView and UIView components can be wrapped in it.